# How to Initialize class member that is a pointer to a structure

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, crash, runtime

> I have a problem with the application crashing at the line of code where if(!head) is being referenced inside the function: insertNode(). head and tail are class members of type node*. It looks like, I am missing something in the way the class members: head, tail are initialized.. 
>   This is the runtime error: "Unhandled exception at 0x00245246 in SLinkedlist_array.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

```
    slinkedlist.h:
    typedef struct node
    {
        int value;
        struct node* next;
    } node;

    class slinkedlist
    {
    public:
        //ctor, dtor, insertNode(int, int), displayList()
    private:
        node* head, tail;
    };

    slinkedlist.cpp:
    bool slinkedlist::insertNode(int value, int aftNodeVal)
    {
        int toinsertval = value;
        int searchkey = aftNodeVal;
        bool retval = false;

        // If it's a new linked list
        if(!head)  // THIS IS WHERE THE APPLICATION CRASHES!
        {
            node* head = new node;
            head->value = toinsertval;
            head->next = NULL;
            return true;
        }
        else //It's not a new list
        {
            while(head->next != NULL)
            {
                 //some more code here... 
            }
        }
        return retval;
    }

    void slinkedlist::displayList()
    {
        while(!head)
        {
            do
            {
                cout << head->value << " " ;
                head = head->next;
            }
            while(head->next != NULL);
        }
        //return void;
    }

    main.cpp:
    int main()
    {
        slinkedlist *s1 = NULL;
        s1->insertNode(4, -1);
        s1->displayList();
        while(1);
    }`
```

Comment: You `s1->insertNode(4, -1);`, but `s1` has not initialized.

Comment: Unrelated: The `typedef`ing of `typedef struct node { int value; struct node* next; } node;` is not necessary. C++ is more than smart enough to figure out what node is without it. `struct node { int value; struct node* next; };` is sufficient.

Comment: Related: Read up on the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: Depending on how and where you define a variable, it may or may not be initialized. [Some reading on those rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). In this case you're right and the problem is initialization. `head` and `tail` are not being initialized. [Here's a link to documentation on the may different ways you can initialize in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization). Pick the one that makes the most sense. But...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
slinkedlist *s1 = NULL;
```

defines a pointer to a `slinkedlist` and DOES initialize it Unfortunately it initializes it to NULL, a safe parking address where (usually) no object are allowed to exist. For the vast majority of CPUs (every CPU I've ever worked on) accessing this dead zone around NULL will crash the program, making it much easier to detect bugs.

There is no need for a pointer here. If you don't need  pointer, don't use one. Your life will be much easier.

```
int main()
{
    slinkedlist s1; // default initializes
    s1.insertNode(4, -1);
    s1.displayList();
    while(1); // rethink this. If you want to hold a program open to see the output 
              // while debugging, place a breakpoint in the debugger.   
}
```

[Default initializing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) of `s1` alone will not help you because it will do the absolute minimum work to initialize its member variables, and in the case of a pointer the minimum work is to do nothing and leave `head` and `tail` uninitialized and pointing (sort of. `tail` is NOT a pointer) to an indeterminate location. Because you aren't also asking about the compiler error you should get from assigning `NULL` to `tail`, the program is clearly not initializing `tail` and I'll assume the `slinkedlist` constructor doesn't do much.

Side note: If you have a constructor or destructor that don't do anything (and don't need to do anything) leave them out and let the compiler generate the appropriate code. Code that does not exist (and doesn't need to exist) has no bugs.

```
class slinkedlist
{
public:
    //ctor, dtor, insertNode(int, int), displayList()
private:
    node* head, tail; // the * only applies to head.
};
```

could be

```
class slinkedlist
{
public:
    //ctor, dtor, insertNode(int, int), displayList()
private:
    node* head = nullptr;
    node* tail = nullptr;
};
```

if you are compiling to recent (2011 or newer) C++ Standards. You won't need a constructor, the work is done for you with the default assignments. You will still need a destructor along with a copy constructor and an assignment operator to satisfy [The Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

In older C++ Standards you need to make the constructor smarter

```
class slinkedlist
{
public:
    slinkedlist(): head(NULL), tail(NULL)
    {
    }
    //dtor, insertNode(int, int), displayList()
private:
    node* head; // I recommend splitting the definitions up. It makes the code easier 
                // to read and makes it harder to make mistakes.
    node* tail;
};
```

You will still need a destructor, a copy constructor, and an assignment operator.

Note that this also applies to `node`. If you dynamically allocate a node and do not explicitly set `next` to a value, you won't know where `next` points, and all of the tests like

```
while(head->next != NULL)
```

will fail horribly.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs! I've tried out like most of you pointed out, it was the NULL pointer instantiation that I had to fix and the program works okay now.Tha

Comment: @Manasa,Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers.

Comment: @ Jeaninez - MSFT, sure I've marked the answers that helped me.

Comment: @ Jeaninez - MSFT, I hope I have marked the answers that were useful the way you had suggested. Just checking with you, since I'm new to posting on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: you have null-pointer dereference here:

```cpp
slinkedlist *s1 = NULL;
s1->insertNode(4, -1);
s1->displayList();
```

That's what exactly the system tells to you: "Access violation reading location 0x00000000"

Solution can be like:

```cpp
slinkedlist *s1 = new slinkedlist;
s1->insertNode(4, -1);
s1->displayList();
delete s1;
```

Or like this (why not to use just an object on the stack?):

```cpp
slinkedlist s1;
s1.insertNode(4, -1);
s1.displayList();
```

Or more C++ way (if you NEED a pointer):

```cpp
auto s1 = make_unique<slinkedlist>(); // s1 is a std::unique_ptr<slinkedlist>
s1->insertNode(4, -1);
s1->displayList();
```